# Getting the selected RadioButton in LWUIT

Tags: java, java-me, lwuit

Hey people? I have a challenge in getting the selected item from two `RadionButtons` (male and Female) using LWUIT on the J2ME platform.

```
RadioButton selected = genderGroup.getRadioButton(genderGroup.getSelectedIndex());
String selectedGender = selected.toString();
```

I tried the block of code above but never got what I expected.

Would someone please give me a hand.

Regards,
Kevin.

Answer (score 3):

I suppose what you want to extract from the `RadioButton` is the text associated to this `RadioButton`. To do this you need to use `getText()` instead `toString()`.

Is that what you want to do?

Answer (score 1):

hey kevintich Please use This Code...

```
ComponentGroup radioGroup = new ComponentGroup();
final RadioButton defaultBorder = new RadioButton("Default");
radioGroup.addComponent(defaultBorder);
final RadioButton etchedBorder = new RadioButton("Etched Raised Theme");
radioGroup.addComponent(etchedBorder);
final RadioButton etchedColors = new RadioButton("Etched Raised Colors");
radioGroup.addComponent(etchedColors);
final RadioButton etchedLowBorder = new RadioButton("Etched Lowered Theme");
radioGroup.addComponent(etchedLowBorder);
final RadioButton etchedLowColors = new RadioButton("Etched Lowered Colors");
radioGroup.addComponent(etchedLowColors);
final RadioButton bevelBorder = new RadioButton("Bevel Raised Theme");
radioGroup.addComponent(bevelBorder);
final RadioButton bevelColors = new RadioButton("Bevel Raised Colors");
radioGroup.addComponent(bevelColors);
final RadioButton bevelLowBorder = new RadioButton("Bevel Lowered Theme");
radioGroup.addComponent(bevelLowBorder);
final RadioButton bevelLowColors = new RadioButton("Bevel Lowered Colors");
radioGroup.addComponent(bevelLowColors);
final RadioButton roundBorder = new RadioButton("Round Theme");
radioGroup.addComponent(roundBorder);
final RadioButton roundColors = new RadioButton("Round Colors");
radioGroup.addComponent(roundColors);
RadioButton disabledRadioButton = new RadioButton("Disabled Radio Button");
disabledRadioButton.setEnabled(false);
radioGroup.addComponent(disabledRadioButton);
f.addComponent(radioGroup);
```

Comment: No arun. This is not right answer. You said how to add the components.